# grabbing the file description from details tab

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I want to be able to grab the File description string from the details tab on a .dll or a .sys file. I've tried to do this in a number of methods, but can't get them to click. Is there anyway to do this through the command line to get it to produce an output to the screen. I've had no joy with FileVersion.description that is available using VB.

Any direction or help would be much appreciated here.

Thanks

Comment: I have previous managed to get the fileVersion using fso.getFileVersion(argshere) 

I would love it if there was something similar for fileDescription

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
langs = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(ExecutablePath, r'\VarFileInfo\Translation')
key = r'StringFileInfo\%04x%04x\FileDescription' %(langs[0][0], langs[0][1])        
print (win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(ExecutablePath, key))
```

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point it looks like some of this stuff can be retrieved using [win32api](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). You can find documentation [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html), and of course using python's built-in help().

I edited to add some code to show how some of the information can be retrieved. I've used win32api as well as [os.stat](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) Hope this is enough to get you started. Shouldn't be too hard to find the rest of it with what I've given so far.

```
import os
import time
import stat
from win32api import GetFullPathName

def get_details(file_name):
    time_format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"
    file_stats = os.stat(file_name)

    return {
        'folder_path': GetFullPathName(file_name),
        'size': file_stats[stat.ST_SIZE],
        'date_modified':time.strftime(time_format,time.localtime(file_stats[stat.ST_MTIME])),
        'access_time': time.strftime(time_format,time.localtime(file_stats[stat.ST_ATIME])),
    }

print get_details("myfilename")
```

Comment: This is good stuff. I need the actual File Description too, I don't believe that is available through os.stat.

Comment: Not sure about that. I have not used it myself, but some quick research seems to indicate that this might do what you want: [WMI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/)